# I don't want to apply a property of a CSS class to an element in the list

Tags: html, css

I've made a class in CSS:

```
.nav{
    display: block;
    background-color: #5271ff;
    position: fixed;
    height: 160px;
    width: 100%;
    padding:0;

.nav li{
     float: left;
     padding-top: 130px;
     padding-left: 10px;


}
```

My HTML code is

```
<div class="nav">

            <ul>
                <li>
                    <img src="logo.png" alt = "logo" width="160" height="160">
                </li>

                <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li><li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
            </ul>


        </div>
```

Is it possible NOT to apply the property to the image which is part of the list?
The outcome is always pushing the image out of the block that I've made, my idea is that the block is gonna have the color of the logo and they will mix together and I want the "Home" and "News" on the bottom of the block, not on top of it. I'm fairly new to HTML and css.

Comment: I suggest that you try "Inspect" from Chrome, Firefox and other browsers. Right click on the displayed page, then select Inspect. You should then be able to update your CSS interactively in your browser. Once you see something that seems to work, update your CSS definitions and/or HTML files and re-test to confirm that the desired results were obtained.

Comment: Your CSS is invalid (no end bracket for the `.nav` class definition), and your HTML might not work the way you want (extra `<li>` start tag). Just a heads up on why things might not be working.

Comment: After you fix the problems from the previews comment try adding this class in CSS: .nav li img {height:100%;width:auto}. If i have properly understood your question this should make the logo float in the right spot. With this class you will make the img scale according to the height of the li that contains it. You can also try using height:auto;width:100% to make the img scale according to the width of the li. Goog luck

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried nav li:not(:first-child)
 instead of nav li 
It will leave the first li and apply the style to the others. You can actually use a class but I think the not function is handy in this case that how I would have done it myself #cheers

Answer (score 0):

Give a common class to the elements of the list you want to have common properties. You can then specify an ID for the items you want to give different properties to.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could achieve this.

If the image is always going to be in the first li you could apply the below css:

```
.nav li:first-child ~ li {
     float: left;
     padding-top: 130px;
     padding-left: 10px;
}
```

or you could apply a class to all the elements you want the styles to effect:

```
.nav .item {
     float: left;
     padding-top: 130px;
     padding-left: 10px;
}
```

or you could apply a class to the image li and use :not

```
.nav li:not(.image) {
     float: left;
     padding-top: 130px;
     padding-left: 10px;
}
```

The above are all viable solutions, and CSS usually has several ways to achieve the same result. It all depends on the approach you want, if you have direct access to the HTML and how scalable you want the CSS and markup to be.